# Strategies for exposing user identification from a REST endpoint back to the data-access/repository layer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

The background: there is a requirement to attach auditing data to persisted entities, basically creation-timestamp + user ID and last-update-timestamp + user ID.

I'm not keen on passing the user ID as a method parameter through all layers/components. So I need to somehow pass user identifcation (derived from HTTP headers, the details are unimportant) through a REST endpoint (using RESTEasy, but that's probably not important, either) back to the data access/repository layer.

I've thought of using `ThreadLocal` but it feels a little hackish and might fail in a non-blocking IO environment. Maybe I'm wrong about that, not sure.

I also have a vague idea that AOP could help, though I'm not well-versed in AOP so not sure.

Any strategies appreciated, with or without code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Spring's [`SecurityContextHolder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) is a reasonable place to do this (don't ask why the application isn't already integrating "properly" with Spring Security). It's basically the `ThreadLocal` option but with some nice interface around it.

The tradeoff is that you need to be acutely aware of the thread-bound nature of this solution. A controller that somehow uses other thread to do the work that needs the user context, will need to take some steps to make sure those threads can get it since they don't, by default, inherit the `ThreadLocal`. There is a mode you can set on `SecurityContextHolder` that will use inheritance of the `ThreadLocal` in any newly created threads, but that does not help if a thread pool is used (since threads won't be created by the request thread but rather pulled from the pool). Even then, most thread pools provide a way for the client thread to do "something" when obtaining and releasing threads, so it's possible to pass the security context on that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [entity lifecycle callback methods](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html) for your requirement: `@PrePersist`, `@PostPersist`, `@PreUpdate`, `@PostUpdate`.

It is one of the auditing strategies mentioned [here](http://blog.eisele.net/2011/01/five-ways-to-know-how-your-data-looked.html?m=1).

Comment: That doesn't really help. I know the options for actually inserting data into persisted entities, what I'm asking is for strategies to get the user identification information  in the data access layer.

Comment: This post can be a comment, but this can also be an answer. The question is asking for strategies (with or without code), and at least I tried to give a direct possible answer, but apparently not an accepted one according to the OP.

Comment: This answer (or comment) totally misunderstands the question.